# Bind 9.10.4-P4 not available on ubuntu?

Tags: bind

I am currently running ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS with BIND 9.10.3-P4 that is the latest available version of bind on the ubuntu repositories. 
I was informed that the current version that I am running is vulnerable and we should update to Bind 9.10.4-P3 or later. Should I use ISC version of bind and remove the ubuntu one?

Comment: 9.10.4 is not mentioned in the changelog or am i not looking correctly?

Comment: What vulnerability are we talking about? CVE-2016-8864 is [fixed in Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3119-1/).

Comment: the version of ISC BIND running on the remote name server is 9.9.x prior to 9.9.9-P3, 9.10.x prior to 9.10.4-P3, or 9.11.x prior to 9.11.0rc3. It is, therefore, affected by a denial of service vulnerability within file buffer.c due to improper construction of responses to crafted requests. An unauthenticated, remote attacker can exploit this, via a specially crafted query, to cause an assertion failure, resulting in a daemon exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vulnerability you are referring to in the comments is [CVE-2016-2776](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-2776). It was [fixed in Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3088-1/) in version `1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.1` of the BIND packages. You can check your installed version with `dpkg -l | grep bind`, and if you have at least that version, you can disregard the notice you received, as it does not apply to you.

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm currently running 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.2